# How to full screen layout to a view in Swift?

Tags: swift, layout, view, storyboard, constraints

Im trying to my MapView fill on screen on ipad, iphone or landspace..
I set constraints like this

[image].

Its working on first time but I rotate device its not fill screen. Why? How I set the view fill the screen on storyboard or code?

[this is how to look my constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyyIy.png)

I use this code in ViewDidLoad:

```
googleMapsView.frame = view.bounds
```

Its working first load. And I search rotate function and try this on that:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    googleMapsView.frame = view.bounds        
}
```

Its not working again..

Comment: Provide more detail with screen shots

Comment: when I change device on storyboard its working fill screen. But not working on real devices. I use iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is very vague. Maybe you messed up with your constraints? Try setting the constricts to the size of the screen instead of a specific height and width. [image: make sure each thing is set to 0]

Make sure each thing is set to 0

Comment: But I dont want specific height and width. I just want to my view fit the screen every device. Just this.

Comment: That is what this constraint does

Comment: I added my constraints look like on my question

Comment: Can you show me what you storyboard layout looks like and your hierarchy?

Comment: I added my question this link: this is how to look my constraints

Comment: I think I found your problem. Do you wan the image to fill the whole screen or just the google maps views? Also, is your image a picture or a solid color?

Comment: just the google maps view. I can another image to fill the screen. its picture of legends map

Comment: Try using aspect ratio, with the constraints you already have

Comment: What happens when you rotate the device, I need to know how the image move or expands or if it disappears

Comment: That's how to look map on device:


 first: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux0ez.jpg
 when i rotate device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrgZ6.jpg
 when i back rotate device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSSqA.jpg

Comment: Your constraints for the image need to be for the whole container. Delete the constraints, make the image bigger, add the constraints then adjust the size, then fix the error.

Comment: I try. Not working. Also i remove image and not working too.

Comment: Are you having problem with the image or the google maps view?

Comment: Google maps view

Comment: Do what I wrote an hour ago "Your constraints for the image need to be for the whole container. Delete the constraints, make the image bigger, add the constraints then adjust the size, then fix the error." But for the google maps view

Comment: Please post the answer then or mark mine as correct

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Drag your `UIView` to Safe Area, choose Equal Height and do the same for the Width.

Answer (score -3):

Check my screenshot:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Drag with control key pressed from view to superview will set constraints like this.

- Center Horizontalliy in Container
- Center Vertically in Container
- Equal Widths
- Equal Heights